Nuxt project can't be initiated
npx nuxi init@latest
ERROR  Error: Failed to download https://codeload.github.com/nuxt/starter/tar.gz/refs/heads/v3 : TypeError: fetch failed                                                                           09:49:07
I Tried redownloading Node js, it hasn't helped, looking for in internet tried to go by the link but it shows like there's some bad on that site

What's your node version? Are you behind a proxy, firewall or something that could block the download? Does it happen only with Nuxt? I remember I saw that error before. Maybe you're trying to download it from China?

My node is last but not LTS. I don't know what can I be behind even. Yeah it started happening only with Nuxt, no I wasn't trying to download it from china I actually live in Russia. Additionally I did something in terminal I haven't written cause I don't remember

The current LTS is v20.15.0, don't use any uneven versions, and no point in using the non-official one now either. If you forgot a command you typed, you can always find it back by using history as a command in your terminal. Not sure if it can help, but maybe try to use your phone as a hotspot and connect your computer to it, then try to download it from there. Might not work anyway because you're in Russia, but might be worth giving a try. Might also be difficult to solve if it's a political conflict issue. Maybe try with a VPN, not sure how good is the security outbound of the country.

Otherwise, you can also git clone the Nuxt3 start from here, should do pretty much the same at the end of the day, npx nuxi init does not do any crazy magic.

I appreciate it, will try
